# Manipulating dateValue doesn't update DatePicker's UI properlly

Tags: javascript, date, sapui5

I'm using the [`sap.m.DatePicker`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.m.DatePicker). Over a Button I increase the current date by one day.

```js
date = datePicker.getDateValue();
date = date.setDate(date.getDate() +1);
datePicker.setDateValue(new Date(date));
```

But the date increases only in the calendar part of the picker, not in the input field.

[image: screenshot of my DatePicker after update]

Am I doing something wrong or is it some bug?

Comment: Please avoid calling `rerender` that was suggested in the other answer. It's not a public method and it's also deprecated! Better assign a new JS date object as suggested in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63091838/5846045

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can re-render the control if changes in control's data is not getting reflected in UI.

Use [`rerender`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Control.html#rerender) as below after updating value of `DatePicker` control.

```
datepicker.rerender();
```

Comment: Please avoid recommending protected/private APIs such as `rerender` (It's also deprecated by now).

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann Please check the date of the answer on which it was posted (before downvoting answer if you have), at that moment the method was not deprecated. Also, the method is neither protected nor private.  [rerender](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.Control%23methods/rerender)

Comment: I'm aware of the date but had to downvote for future readers: the [`rerender` API has been _protected_ since the beginning](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blame/8d01e43bee43a69b199a052c493ecfc692e18543/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/Control.js#L379). This can be also seen in the API reference (Visibility: protected). Also `rerender` forces the control to rewrite its DOM synchronously. Forcing to rewrite the DOM node, as an app dev, is often an indicator that that there is something wrong with the current approach. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63091838) I suggested what could be improved

Answer (score 0):

You have to manipulate the new date instance instead of the old one from the control.

> ```js
> const newDate = new Date(datePicker.getDateValue().getTime()); // create a new copy
> newDate.setDate(datePicker.getDateValue().getDate() +1); // manipulate the new date instead
> datePicker.setDateValue(newDate);
> ```

<sup>From: https://jsbin.com/hulopec/edit?js,output</sup>

Since JS dates are objects, and since objects in JS are *shared* across other reference holders, manipulating the original date value will cause a side effect in control's internal value as well.

In general, using `const` instead of `var` could help avoiding such accidental side effects.